# how to pass dynamically value to where condition if the specific value exists in array?

Tags: php, sql

I'm sending values from ajax to PHP as an associative array, depending on some values i should include statement into `WHERE` statement. For example i have this kind of array

```
Array
(
    [project_name] => Riverside
    [property_type] => For Rent
    [rooms] => default
)
```

if rooms value is equal to default, i should not use WHERE statement for rooms so it looks like this.

```
$sql = SELECT Property_Type, Property_Name, Rooms from  appartment
             WHERE Project_Name = :project_name AND
              Property_Type = :property_type;
```

in case if array rooms is equal to 2, sql statement should look like this

```
$sql = SELECT Property_Type, Property_Name, Rooms from  appartment
             WHERE Project_Name = :project_name AND
              Property_Type = :property_type AND Rooms = 2;
```

I don't want to write to separate sql statements, since this will apply as well for `project_name` and project_type if the values is `All projects` it should not use `Project_Name` in Where statement.

Can anyone explain how can i achieve this?

Comment: `$sql = 'SELECT etc etc without AND rooms part'; 'if ($array['rooms'] == 2) { $sql .= ' AND Rooms = 2';`}

Comment: @delboy1978uk What if  rooms conditions comes first? `FROM appartment WHERE AND Rooms = 2`...?

Comment: One common approach is to have something like: `AND (Rooms = :rooms OR :rooms IS NULL)`  So you can bind the value whether or not it's NULL, the query will just logically ignore it if it's NULL.

Comment: why would it? don't you always select a project first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically build your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Property_Type, Property_Name, Rooms from  appartment';
$where = [];
$params = [];

foreach ($_GET['WhereConditions'] as $key => $value) {
    switch($key) {
        case 'rooms':
            if ($value == 2) {
                $where[] = "`Rooms` = :roomsCount";
                $params[':roomsCount'] = 2;
            }

            break;
         ...
    }
}

if (!empty($where)) {
     $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode('AND', $where);
}

$db->prepare($sql)->fetchAll($params);
```